# Delete all equal items from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next situation in my react application:
I have a state:

```js
const [arr1, setArr1] = useState([1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3]);
```

Bellow i render all items from array on UI like:

```js
arr1.map(i => <li>{i}</li>)
```

Now i want to remove **all** items that are equal in the array:
ex:

1. [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3] // should be deleted 1 and 3 result: [1, 2, 5]
2. [1, 2, 3, 5, 3] // should be deleted 3  result: [1, 2, 5] 
   Deleting all items also the state should change here `arr1.map()`. 
   I tried `setArr1([new Set(arr1)])`, but it does not delete all duplicated values, it delete just one of them.
   How to achieve what i described above?

Comment: Shouldn't 1 be removed from this `[1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3]` ?

Comment: @HassanImam, yes, all `1` should be removed

Comment: @HassanImam It's someone who's averaging a question per hour regarding what appears to be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12540500/asking So I'm pretty sure they themselves are thoroughly bewildered by what they want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate array values and then storing them \[react\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217953/removing-duplicate-array-values-and-then-storing-them-react)

Answer (score 4):

You can count the frequency of number and then just pick the number whose frequency is 1.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3],
      frequency = arr.reduce((o,v) => (o[v] = (o[v] || 0) + 1, o), {}),
      unique = Object.keys(frequency).reduce((r,k) => frequency[k] === 1? [...r, +k]: r, []);
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: could you take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381227/change-the-state-according-to-event-in-reactjs. You will help me a lot. This is something related to this question but i can't figure out how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the frequency and remove the number if the frequency is greater than 1. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-snowflake-ljmhi?file=/src/App.js)

```
    function removeDuplicates(arr) {
    const frequency = {};
    arr.forEach((el) => {
      frequency[el] = frequency[el] ? ++frequency[el] : 1;
    });

    const result = [];
    for (el in frequency) {
      if (frequency[el] === 1) {
        result.push(el);
      }
    }

    return result;
 }
  

    const arrayWithoutDuplicates = removeDuplicates(arr1);
      return (
        <ul>
          {arrayWithoutDuplicates.map((el) => {
            return <li key={el}> {el} </li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      );
```

Comment: i need to remove both duplicated values.

Comment: @Asking updated, Check if this your required code

Comment: could you take a look on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381227/change-the-state-according-to-event-in-reactjs. I can't figure out how to solve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check if the the first index equal to the last index on an element,when they are equals it means it is unique:

```js
let result = []
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3]

arr.forEach(e => arr.indexOf(e) === arr.lastIndexOf(e)?result.push(e):null)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: What is that another question or it is related to this one?

Comment: it is another, but i think the idea probably is  related with this. I can't solve it. Could you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a one-liner using filter

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3];

const unique = arr.filter(x => arr.filter(y => y === x).length < 2)
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Your solution has a time complexity of O(n^2). @Hassan Imam's solution has a complexity of of just O(2n). His solution is more optimised