# Obtaining unique entries only using setState?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am currently able to display my meals output, however, there are duplicates that show up. To compensate, I tried to use the logic seen here: [Removing duplicate array values and then storing them [react]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217953/removing-duplicate-array-values-and-then-storing-them-react). However, now my list disappears. If I can get some help, I would much appreciate it as I have been trying to debug this for quite a bit. Thank you!

Relevant code:

```
  const [meals, setMeals] = React.useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getMeals();
    }, []);

    function getMeals() {
        console.log(route.params.DiningID);
        fetch(`a https url`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
                        // Successful GET
                        // Set Fields to correct values
                        response.json().then(function(data) {

                            setMeals(data.map(menuItem => ({ label: menuItem.menu_item.item_name, value: menuItem.menu_item.menu_item_id })));
                            // having trouble with the unique output
                            setMeals(meals
                                .map(e => e['value'])
                                 // store the keys of the unique objects
                                 .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
                                 // eliminate the dead keys & store unique objects
                                 .filter(e => meals[e]).map(e => meals[e]));
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Getting Dining Menu Items like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                            response.status);
                    }
                }
            )
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to remember that the `setMeals` command is asynchronous.

See: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)
.

For this reason, you call `setMeals` on the new data, then immediately after refer to `meals`, but it is possible (likely) that `meals` does not contain the new values yet.

Since `meals` is initialized to an empty array `[]`, the `map` and `filter` chain results in another empty array `[]`. You then call `setMeals` on an empty array, which is why your list disappears.

In a synchronous context, you're performing an operation similar to:

```
meals = [...A Bunch of New Data]
meals = []
```

The second `setMeals` overwrites the data you tried to add.

You might try to map and filter the `data` directly and make a single `setMeals` call.

```js
setMeals(data
    .map(e => e.menu_item.menu_item_id)
    .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
    .filter(e => data[e])
    .map(e => data[e])
    .map(menuItem => ({
        label: menuItem.menu_item.item_name,
        value: menuItem.menu_item.menu_item_id
    })));
```